# $.ajax function's success: not firing

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a $.ajax function that POSTS a data.

i have success: `function(){alert("successflly posted")}`

i check Firebug console, ajax request is POSTED and completed successfully, hOWEVER, the alert message never fires.

Comment: Can you post the entire `$.ajax` call?  Are you getting any Javascript errors in the error console?

Answer (score 4):

There's probably some error. Try setting the error callback:

```
error: function(httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
   alert("status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);
}
```

That may tell you why it's not working

Answer (score 0):

A great suggestion by Philippe.

You could also try setting breakpoints/watches in firebug to see where your code is actually going (or not going).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the $.post() method, which is a wrapper for the more complicated $.ajax() method.

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind posting the entire block of code here?  A couple of quick notes- if you are using firebug, you don't need to use the alert() method, instead, use console.log()