# jQuery ajax success event Strangely not working on ajaxSetup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Background:**

- Using jQuery 1.7 client side
- PHP server side
- Using json responses with json_encode php function
- The content-type header is correct, any of these works: text/plain,text/x-json,application/json.
- There's no errors thrown from my php code
- Am working on Firefox 11
- Am using the js console and the other web's developer tools
- HTTP/1.1 200 OK

In this Javascript code, the `success` event is never fired:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false,
        success:function(d) {
            console.log("ok from setup with data "+d.toSource())
        },
        complete:function(xhr,ts){
            console.log("Ajax finished reponse:"+xhr.responseText)
        },
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("Error")
        }
});
$.getJSON("test2.php",{},function(data){
    //some code here
});
```

When I do it this way, it works:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false,                
        complete:function(xhr,ts){
            console.log("Ajax completado con:"+xhr.responseText)
        },
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("Error")
        }
});
$.getJSON("test2.php",{},
     function(data){
            //some code here
     }).success(function(d){
            console.log("success applied directly, data "+d.toSource())
        }
);
```

In both cases the complete event is always fired and the error one never.
**However, in the second code the success is fired.**
Obviously for `.get()` method it's the same.

#### PHP code:

```
<?php header("Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8");
    //or whatever text/x-json text/plain, even text/html, jquery do the dirty job
echo json_encode(array("stat"=>"1")) ?>
```

**My objectives:**

1. I want to fire the same success event to all ajax requests
2. I want to use the json *data* returned by the request in my success event, and if it is possible, without convert the raw jqXHR responseText to a json *again*

The problem is strange, any ideas?

---

I read all these questions:

- [Ajax success event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969476/ajax-success-event-not-working)
- [AjaxSetup never execute the success function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390454/ajaxsetup-never-execute-the-success-function)
- [Does jQuery ajaxSetup method not work with $.get or $.post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542939/does-jquery-ajaxsetup-method-not-work-with-get-or-post)
- [$.ajax function's success: not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407905/ajax-functions-success-not-firing)

And I'm pretty sure none of them are my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the ajaxSetup documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

> Note: Global callback functions should be set with their respective
>   global Ajax event handler methods—.ajaxStart(), .ajaxStop(),
>   .ajaxComplete(), .ajaxError(), .ajaxSuccess(), .ajaxSend()—rather than
>   within the options object for $.ajaxSetup().

I think that's your problem right there.

UPDATE

If you want your ajax handlers to be global for *any* ajax request on the page, do something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(d){
    console.log("ok from setup with data "+d.toSource());
});
```

Comment: ok i get that, but that i really want is to fire the same success event to all ajax request to do some stuff, but without add ajaxSuccess() to each object. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Try this: `$(document).ajaxSuccess(...)`

Comment: Also, what browser are you using? `.toSource` is Gecko-only.

Comment: yes that's can be a solution, but there's a problem the i dont especify very well my needs, i have to do some stuff with the json object returned

Comment: I'm assuming that my solution works based on the example in your question.  Is that true?  If there's more to it than that, you'll need to update your question.

Comment: The ajaxSuccess() recieves (event,xhr,options) and the success recieves (**data**,textStatus,xhr) and for my needs i need that data y i dont want to convert _again_ the raw responseText to a json object if jquery do it once. But am not going to get strict about it. Thanks for your solution. By the way my browser it's firefox 11, and, yes the .toSource function is not standard

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now.  I guess I haven't dealt with ajax global handlers enough to encounter that.  Here's a link that could probably help with that: http://www.pixelastic.com/blog/70:missing-data-in-jquery-ajax-event-ajaxsuccess

Comment: Excellent Dan! I found a comment by Ben Kojabash in that web site and he's totally right the .ajaxSuccess actually recieves as 4th param the data, but that's not documented in the official jquery API. There's no need to use $.httpData() or $.parseJSON(). Thanks

Comment: Very cool.  :)  I'll upvote any comment that confirms an undocumented feature of jQuery.